Disable Ctrl + Shift shortcut to choose input method
I have a Lenovo Tab K10, Android 12, using Gboard. I'm trying to use Ctrl + Shift + arrow from an external keyboard to select words, however, Ctrl + Shift causes the "Choose input method" popup window to show up

The selection of words is fine, but it's interrupted by this window.
Is there a way to disable this shortcut in Android?

What Android device (model, manufacturer) do you use and which Android version is installed?

It's android 12, Lenovo Tab K10. They are asking me to update, but I'm afraid the update can add more problems instead.
